# nice command in C

Tags: c, linux, process, nice

I wrote a program that realizes the equivalent of the `nice` command in linux.

How can I modify the program to report the failure to stderr, take over and execute a simple command?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>

int my_nice(int incr)
{
    /* adjusts the nicess value of a process by +incr.
       Returns -1 on failure.
       Returns new priority on success.
    */

    int prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    if (setpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0, prio + incr) == -1)
        return -1;

    prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    return prio;
}

int main(void)
{
    int prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    printf("Current priority = %d\n", prio);

    printf("\nAdding +5 to the priority\n");
    my_nice(5);
    prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    printf("Current priority = %d\n", prio);

    printf("\nAdding -7 to the priority\n");
    my_nice(-7);
    prio = getpriority(PRIO_PROCESS, 0);
    printf("Current priority = %d\n", prio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which failure do you mean?

Comment: Are asking about the `exec` function and its family, i.e. how to start replace your process with a different one?

Comment: @knittl yes, that

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`exec()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) family of functions to replace your current process image with a new process image.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 2) {
      /* check argc/argv to contain enough arguments */
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* change priority here */

    return execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
    /* argv[0] contains the name of your current program */
    /* argv[1] contains the first command line argument */
    /* argv + 1 points to all arguments except the name of the current executable */
}
```

`execvp` will look up programs in PATH. If you require users of your program to provide the full path to the binary, use `execv`. In other words `./yourprogram ls` will only work with `execvp`, not with `execv`. `execvp` requires you to call `./yourprogram /bin/ls`.

Since GNU coreutils' nice binary is open source and freely available, you can also take a look at its source code: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/master/src/nice.c. It uses a similar `execvp` call.